# python config file error

Tags: python, configuration, configparser

I have a program that updates information to an ini file but when I try to do this I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Programming\Math-Bot\Math-Bot.py", line 106, in check
    config.write()
TypeError: write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'
```

But I can't seem to find the what I need to do,

this is my code to write to the config file:

```
user = 'default'
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('settings.ini')
config[user]['wrong'] = str( int(config[user]['wrong']) + 1 )
config.write()
```

and this is the config file:

```
[default]
wrong=0
```

Any Ideas I really need help!

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: What is `config` object?

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code. What is config? I'm guessing 'fp' is a file pointer. Maybe you forgot to open the file, or you did but id failed for some reason?

Comment: I have updated it so I hope that gives you an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> **`write`**`(fileobject, space_around_delimiters=True)`
>
> Write a representation of the configuration to the specified file object, which must be opened in text mode (accepting strings).

So you problem is, you are missing the file-object argument from the write method:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
# do some configuration here

with open('settings.ini', 'w') as settings:
    config.write(settings)  # write to a file
```